# Get file system type in AIX

Tags: nfs, command-line-interface, aix

I want to fetch the file system types in AIX like NFS and all. du command shows just the file systems not their types. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you execute command `mount` you will get output like this:

```
node   mounted          mounted over  vfs    date              options   
----   -------          ------------ ---  ------------   -------------------
       /dev/hd0         /            jfs   Dec 17 08:04   rw, log  =/dev/hd8
       /dev/hd3         /tmp         jfs   Dec 17 08:04   rw, log  =/dev/hd8
       /dev/hd1         /home        jfs   Dec 17 08:06   rw, log  =/dev/hd8
       /dev/hd2         /usr         jfs   Dec 17 08:06   rw, log  =/dev/hd8
sue    /home/local/src  /usr/code    nfs   Dec 17 08:06   ro, log  =/dev/hd8
```

As you can see the column 4 show the filesystem for particular disk/device as well as other interesting information.

Answer (score 1):

To list the *available* filesystem types, you can look at the `/etc/vfs` file, described by [`man vfs`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.3?topic=files-vfs-file).

To list the currently-mounted filesystems and their types, use `mount` as [Romeo Ninov demonstrated](https://serverfault.com/a/1152056/293440). Alternatively,  the [`lsfs` command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.3?topic=l-lsfs-command) has some useful options, such as: `lsfs -v jfs2` to list filesystems of a particular type (jfs2 here), or `lsfs -c` to list filesystems in a colon-delimited format (useful for subsequent parsing).